# How to disable background compilation until I press the compile button?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am developing a C++ project on a Linux system over SSH with Visual Studio Code.  Now that the the number of CPP files in the project has grown, the Linux system often hits 100% CPU and sometimes grinds to a halt with kswapd0 fixed on 50% CPU and has to be rebooted.

So I want to limit the work the the CPU is doing and one thing I have noticed is that when I am typing in a CPP file in Visual Studio Code, calls are being made to the Linux system to compile the file.  Even after a single key press in a CPP file causes *cpptools* and *cpptools-srv* to hit >80% CPU.

How can I disable this background compiling until I am ready to press the compile button?

Comment: find out which extension is causing this recompile/integration test runs. It is not the default C++ extension. Why recompile while you are typing, that is a sure cause of failure. If you save it could be possible to get a valid compile.

Comment: What about setting `c_cpp.intelliSenseUpdateDelay` to a longer value?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains the answer to itself

Comment: @Richard You may post your findings as an answer yourself, this is valid. Otherwise the question will show as unanswered. If you have a further question about that formatting error you should ask a different question (and research first, of course).

Comment: @anatolyg that's not a close reason. When you see that, you should either comment telling the asker to move the answer to an answer post (you can link them to [answer]), or you should [do it yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587), preferably as a community wiki post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replies pointing my in the right direction.

In settings/extensions/C+C++/IntelliSense:

```
Autocomplete: disabled
Intelli Sense Engine: Tag Parser
Intelli Sense Engine Fallback: disabled
Workspace parsing priority: low
```

This does not completely stop the compilation, but reduces CPU time to <20%.

To completely stop editing compilations, set:

```
Intellisense Engine: disabled
```

There are side effects from completely disabling the Intellisense engine, including the disabling of code formatting.